# QT UDP Socket Returning Empty Datagrams

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

Let me start this by saying this is more than likely a UDP configuration issue than a QT issue.

I am playing a PCAP file using UDP replay on an ubuntu computer to a windows PC.  When I check the UDP data via wireshark, I can see all of the associated data within each packet.  But, when I use my QT program, I get the packet to come through, with the proper length but there is no data inside the packet, just 0s.

I have the IP address of the Windows PC set to be on the same sub-net as the ubuntu source PC as well as the proper port configured.

I am using essentially the QT Multicast Receiver example, here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-multicastreceiver-example.html

Any thoughts?

Edit:

My apologies for not including proper code.

```
void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
 {
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        statusLabel->setText(tr("Received datagram: \"%1\"")
                             .arg(datagram.data()));
    }
}
```

The datagram.data() byte array is simply filled with zeros, no matter what the packet actually contained.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted.  I honestly need some help here.  

Let me flesh this out a little further, if I can.

Each UDP packet I am recieving has a length of 1375 Bytes.  I receive a 1375 byte datagram, but the content is all 0s.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but... you *must* show the relevant code -- preferably a [mcve].  Otherwise it's all just guesswork.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code conveniently ignores the size of the received datagram returned by `readDatagram`; that's one source of possible errors. Things will be much easier by using `receiveDatagram` instead:

```
void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
{
  while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
    auto datagram = udpSocket->receiveDatagram();
    statusLabel->setText(tr("Received datagram: \"%1\"")
                         .arg(QString::fromLatin1(datagram.data().toHex())));
  }
}
```

Now the datagram's contents are hex-encoded and it's easy to tell exactly what's in it *and* how long it is. It's generally speaking **a very bad idea** to pass unsanitized datagram contents as arguments to string output methods, as that makes any UTF-8 decoder bugs potentially exploitable. Use `toHex()` to protect yourself from that. Since `data()` here is not `char * data()` but `QByteArray data()`, the display will show exactly the length received.